# Supervised Machine Learning: Getting weights for each individual parameter for classifications

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a applied scikit decision tree algorithm over my data to get the outcome. Now, I want a mechanism to determine what are the factors that contribute  most to the prediction made by my algorithm in user readable format.

Example: Suppose my training and test data are same as the below table.

```html
<table border='1'>
  <thead>
        <th>Parameter1</th>
        <th>Parameter2</th>
        <th>Parameter3</th>
        <th>Parameter4</th>
        <th>Class</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Success</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>pqr</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
        <td>1.4</td>
        <td>Success</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>0.9</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Failure</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

After applying the algorithm, I able able to predict things with a good precision. Now, what I want is to provide users with weights of all the parameters that have contributed to success/failure of the prediction.

Example:

```html
    <table border='1'>
      <thead>
            <th>Parameter1</th>
            <th>Parameter2</th>
            <th>Parameter3</th>
            <th>Parameter4</th>
            <th>Class</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#FEF3AD;">50%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#00FF00;">80%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#00FF00;">80%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FEF3AD;">50%</td>
            <td>Success</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#00BB00;">100%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#00D500;">90%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#c9ff00;">70%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#00D500;">90%</td>
            <td>Success</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#FEF3AD;">50%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#ff7f39;">10%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#ff1a00;">5%</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FEF3AD;">50%</td>
            <td>Failure</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

So, the second table indicates to what extent the associated parameters are contributing towards the success of that particular row.

---

What I have attempted till now is to have the following mechanism in place:

1. I am finding the correlation coefficient using Kendalltau for all the parameters.
2. For all the parameters, firing group by queries to get the success percent:

> ```
>  SELECT Parameter1, COUNT('SUCCESS')/COUNT(*)
>  FROM table and joins 
>  WHERE clauses
>  GROUP BY Parameter1;
> ```

3. Adding the parameter correlation coefficient to the Success% obtained from the queries. This step is to add the correlation factors to normal statistical percentages.
4. Store each parameter in my database:
   Example:

   > Parameter1, abc, 50%
   >
   > Parameter1, pqr, 100%
   >
   > And so on...

---

Is there a better or more efficient way of doing this? Please provide the details.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`feature_importances_`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) to know the contribution of each feature.
However, the values [`feature_importances_`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) returns do not directly consider prediction accuracy.

For the purpose, you can use `mean decrease accuracy` to evaluate each feature contribution regarding specific evaluation metric.
Following blog post contains good explanation and python sample code.

[Selecting good features – Part III: random forests - Diving into data](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iii-random-forests/)

The main idea of `mean decrease accuracy` is that choosing one feature and permutating randomly the feature values among all instances in the dataset to make the feature meaningless.

```
(A) If accuracy decreases, the selected feature is important for prediction.
(B) If not, the selected feature is not so important for prediction.
```

Merits of using `mean decrease accuracy` are:

```
(1) You can apply it to any classifiers including ensemble models.
(2) You can apply it to any evaluation metric.
```

Comment: The feature_importances_ for my data is always zero for all the features?
I have data with about 10 features and 200 rows. Most of the features have string values and hence I am vectorizing them to create a numpy array. Using the numpy array I am able to predict the classes of all the rows. However, feature_importances_ is always zero. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should return something other than 0 as long as the classifier can reasonably predicts the problem. How do you vectorize the string values? Please copy your code if possible.

Comment: I have 2 datasets in the beginning, training set & test set. What I do is separate features & classes of both and call them train_X, train_Y, predict_X & predict_Y. The train_X & predict_X have same features in same order. However, predict_X features can contain some values not in train_x. Hence I merge the two & convert it into a dictionary of lists and provide it to DictVectorizer as follows:                                                      
vect = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
merged_vect_x = vect.fit_transform(merged_dict_list.values())